# Django templating. Get title of category

Tags: python, html, django, filter, view

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can display the categories title
in my template. Im trying to implement a filter view and this is the last step needed. currently I get the following output

```
Latest Post's in <QuerySet [<Category: testcategory>]>
```

template.html

```
<h1 class="center">Latest Post's in {{ categories }}</h1> < right here!!!
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post">
        <h3><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h3>
        <p>{{ post.content|safe|slice:":1000"|linebreaksbr}}
            {% if post.content|length > 500 %}
                <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">... more</a>
            {% endif %}</p>
        <div class="date">
            <a>Published by: <a href="{% url 'profile' pk=post.author.pk %}">{{ post.author }}</a></a><br>
            <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
            <a>Category: <a href="{% url 'category_by' pk=post.category.pk %}">{{ post.category }}</a></a><br>
            <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a><br>
            <a>Comment(s): {{ post.comment_set.count }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def category_show(request, pk):
    list_posts = Post.objects.get_queryset().filter(category_id=pk).order_by('-pk')
    paginator = Paginator(list_posts, 10)  # Show 10 Posts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myproject/post_list_by_category.html', {'posts': posts, 'categories': categories})
```

Comment: `categories` is a list of `Category`s, so how do you want to present such list?

Comment: its working fine for the list (post in posts) its just about the <h1> line (the very first line of the template).

Comment: Actually i only need to know who i can get only the content of "QuerySet"

Comment: @Vernom: exactly, but `categories` is *not* a *single* `Category`, it is a *collection* of `Category`s, so that means it has no `.title`.

Comment: So you see the problem here ;)
Any workaround ?

Comment: @Venom no "workaround" needed, all you need is to write the correct code to only pass the relevant category instance to your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `categories` is a queryset (a collection of categories), not a single category. What you want is to only select the category matching `pk`:

```
def category_show(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=pk)
    list_posts = Post.objects.filter(category_id=pk).order_by('-pk')
    paginator = Paginator(list_posts, 10)  # Show 10 Posts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'myproject/post_list_by_category.html', {'posts': posts, 'category': category})
```

and

```
<h1 class="center">Latest Post's in {{ category.title }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Category.objects.all() return the query set.If you want use {{ categories.title }} you should use the .get() method

```
def category_show(request, pk):
    list_posts = Post.objects.get_queryset().filter(category_id=pk).order_by('-pk')
    paginator = Paginator(list_posts, 10)  # Show 10 Posts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    cat = Category.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'myproject/post_list_by_category.html', {'posts': posts, 'cat': cat})

<h1 class="center">Latest Post's in {{ cat.title }}</h1> < right here!!!
```

Comment: Even better :D Thank you

Comment: it's not "event better" by any mean - it's the exact same code I posted except 1/ a misnamed variable ("categories" - plural - denotes a collection, when it's a single object) and 2/ it kepts the totally useless `.get_queryset()` call